PHP to extract attribute and value from the given string
Here is my response. I am developing something like b bcode
[quote="abc" post_id='5' time='1728016909' user_id='117']
Around & Business 78
[/quote]

And I need output(Dynamic):
array(
quote=> "abc",
post_id=> '5'
time=> '1728016909'
user_id => '117'
);

I tried following code:
$string = "[quote='abc' post_id='5' time='1728016909' user_id='117']Around & Business 78[/quote]";

    $dom = new DOMDocument;
                    $dom->loadHTML($string); // [quote="abc" ......
                    $attr = array();
                    var_dump($dom->getElementsByTagName('quote'));
                    foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('quote') as $tag) {
                        foreach ($tag->attributes as $attribName => $attribNodeVal){
                            $attr[$attribName]=$tag->getAttribute($attribName);
                        }
                    }
                    echo "<pre>"; print_r($attr);

Please correct easy solution!

It would help if we knew what the input $string is. Can you add this to your question?

This isn't html, this is bbcode.

@KIKOSoftware $string = "[quote="abc" post_id='5' time='1728016909' user_id='117']
Around & Business 78
[/quote]";

@shingo Any solution to extract attribute and value from it?

See also: Parse BBCode in array and Regex & BBCode - Perfecting Nested Quote and BBCode parse quotes and RegEx capturing BBCode Quote username and ID and Matching BBcode inside another bbcode (same tag) and Need regex to grep quote tags
